# Is it possible to get the PERCENT_RANK for a single record, but relative to the entire table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, statistics, percentile

I would like the `PERCENT_RANK` value for a single record, but in relation to the entire table. Is this possible?

Examples I've seen are like this:

```
SELECT Name, Salary
  PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary)
  FROM Employees
```

Notice that it's calculating the percentile for the *returned recordset*. If you're returning the entire table, that's great. But if you're returning a subset, then you're only going to get the percentile for a row *within the returned recordset*, when I want it for the entire table (for a group of rows I *don't* return).

The doc says this:

> Calculates the relative rank of a row within a group of rows

This is not what I want. Basically, I want to do this (note: this is non-working code):

```
SELECT Name, Salary
  PERCENT_RANK() OVER (SELECT * FROM Employees ORDER BY Salary)
  FROM Employees
```

So, effectively, I want to say, "Give me the percentile of this record *when compared to the entire table*."

In the above case, it's one and the same because I'l retrieving the entire table. But I can't pull a single record and gets its percentile rank for the table as a whole.

```
SELECT Name, Salary
  PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary)
  FROM Employees
  WHERE id = 1234
```

That one record will always be `1.000` because it's at the 100% percentile for all the rows returned, which is just the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Salary, r.Employee_Rank
FROM Employees e
    JOIN (
        SELECT id,
        PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary) AS Employee_Rank
        FROM Employees
    ) r ON r.Id = e.Id
WHERE e.id = 1234
```

Comment: Good answer, some explanation would be helpful though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd need to use a subquery or CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT id,
            [Name],
            Salary,
            PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary) AS PR
     FROM Employees)
SELECT [Name],
       Salary,
       PR
FROM CTE
WHERE id = 1234;
```